# magento 1.9 getting values from $_product issue

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working in magento 1.9 . I have around 350 products in backend . When i get the attributes of line items like height , width etc , i am facing the issue . Just like the product "chair" has width = 3.00 , product "paper" has width = 0 and last but not the least product "table" has width = 12.00 . When i print the values of lineitems ,it print the width of chair as 3 , now it should print the width of paper as 0 but **the issue is that it overwrites the previous value in case of 0** . For product table it shows the width as 12 . which is fine . Only issue with 0 values . My code looks like that .

```
 function cortigoLtlProductAttr($_product) {
        $attributes = array(
            'enableLtl'     => 'en_ltl_check',
            'length'        => 'en_length',
            'width'         => 'en_width',
            'height'        => 'en_height',
            'freightClass'  => 'speed_freight_class',
            'hazmat'        => 'en_hazmat',
        ); 
 foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {


                $haveAttribute = $this->checkAttributeAdded($attribute);
                if($haveAttribute){
                    $productAttr[$key] = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                }else{
                    $productAttr[$key] = 'No';
                }
            }
            return $productAttr;
        }
    public function checkAttributeAdded($attributeName){
            $entity = 'catalog_product';
            $attr = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/eav_attribute')
                ->loadByCode($entity,$attributeName);

            if ($attr->getId()) {
                return True;
            }else{
                return False;
            }
        }
```

Looking for kind help .

Answer (score 0):

Use float convertion before echo , or after getting attribute  ,
 like this ->
$price = (float) $price;

Try this , for me it works great !